# Buildroot How do I deal with Error filesystem size (BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE)

Tags: embedded, buildroot

I am usin Buildroot as distro.
I have a problem. I wanted to update my build with adding some packages for my embedded system(stm32mp157).

In menuconfig --> Filesystem images I chose an exact size of 270M which generated the above error.

I tested the exact size and I for

**exact file size inferior to 265M** :mkfs.ext4: Could not allocate block in ext2 filesystem while populating file system
*** Maybe you need to increase the filesystem size (BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE)
fs/ext2/ext2.mk:46: recipe for target '/home/mehdi/buildroot/output/images/rootfs.ext2' failed

**exact file size superior or equal to 265M** I get : part rootfs size (268435456) too small for rootfs.ext4 (283115520)
What should I do? I am beginning my project and I may need further packages and modules for what is coming.

What should I do?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using genimage to create your final SD/MMC image. If this is the case, then your genimage configuration file defines a size of 256 MB for the partition that holds the rootfs, and this size is too small. You need to change your genimage configuration file.

Based on the issue you report, I suppose you're perhaps using the STM32MP1 Buildroot configuration I wrote and published at https://github.com/tpetazzoni/buildroot/blob/2019.02/stm32mp157-dk-blog-7/ together with a series of blog post.

And indeed, the genimage configuration file at https://github.com/tpetazzoni/buildroot/blob/2019.02/stm32mp157-dk-blog-7/board/stmicroelectronics/stm32mp157-dk/genimage.cfg limits the rootfs partition size to 256 MB. Just change that.

Answer (score 2):

After added some python3 modules for rpi3,I lived same problem even my defined size 120M. I changed to 250M for solving.

I guess there is no way to predict how much size we need before compiling.

In the **make menuconfig**:

Filesystem images > exact size (250M)